# Output several cells from inner loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

this is my code:

```
    start() {
  let columns = ['A'...'Z'];

  let fields = {
      id: [
        'Medlemsnummer',      
      ],
      name: [
        'Namn',
      ],
  };
  let out = {};
  let self = this;
  columns.forEach(function(column) {
    for(let row = 1; row < 101; row++) {
      let cell = column + row;
      let d_cell = self.worksheet[cell];
      let val_cell = (d_cell ? d_cell.v : ' ');
      let cell_string = val_cell.toString().toLowerCase();
      let cellString_stripped = cell_string.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
      for (var key in fields) {
          // skip loop if the property is from prototype
          if (!fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
          var obj = fields[key];
          for (var prop in obj) {
              // skip loop if the property is from prototype
              if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
              obj.forEach(function(term) {
                if(cellString_stripped.match(new RegExp(term.toLowerCase() + ".*"))){
                  //out.push(obj + ': ' + cell);
                  //out[obj] = {cell};
                  out[obj] = cell;
                }
              });
              //out[obj]
          }
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(out);
},
```

and my problem is that i want several matched cells in out[obj] = // array of matched cells.

how can i do this in javascript?

so my out should look like this:

```
out = [ medlemsnummer: ['A11','A23','A45'], name: ['B11','B23'] etc... ]
```

please comment if you need me to explain better.

Kind regards,

Joakim

Comment: `out = [ medlemsnummer: ['A11','A23','A45'], name: ['B11','B23'] etc... ]` doesn't look quite right. May be you mean `out = [ { medlemsnummer:
 ['A11','A23','A45'], name: ['B11','B23'] } ]` or something similar?

Comment: Your'e right sorry about that!

Comment: @CommercialSuicide `out` is defined as an object at the top. I suspect it should be `out = { medlemsnummer: ['A11','A23','A45'], name: ['B11','B23'] etc... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your loops, I think you got a little lost in your own structures. `out[obj] = cell` definitely doesn't seem right; `obj` is an object, it cannot be used as a key in another object. Here's my take with some notes, hope I interpreted both your code and your question correctly. I'm starting from the loop after all your variables like `cell`, `d_cell`, etc. are initialized):

```
for (let key in fields) {
    if (!fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    let terms = fields[key];
    // fields[key] yields us an array, e.g.:
    // fields['id'] = [ 'Medlemnummer' ]
    // so we can iterate over it directly with for..of.

    // Note also: variable names like "obj" make reading your code
    // difficult; use meaningful names, e.g. "terms".
    for (let term of terms) {
        let regex = new RegExp(term.toLowerCase() + ".*");

        // Note: RegEx.test() is more efficient than String.match()
        // if all you need is a yes/no answer.
        if (!regex.test(cellString_stripped)) continue;

        // Here's the part you actually needed help with:
        if (!out[term]) {
            out[term] = [];
        }
        out[term].push(cell);
     }
 }
```

Addendum: In the code I'm sticking with your solution to use `RegExp` to test the strings. However, if all you need to check is whether the string starts with the given substring, then it's much shorter and more efficient to use `String.startsWith()`:

```
for (let term of terms) {
    if (!cellString_stripped.startsWith(term.toLowerCase())) continue;

    // Here's the part you actually needed help with:
    if (!out[term]) {
        out[term] = [];
    }
    out[term].push(cell);
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm! thank you so much! You are correct i got lost a bit there with all those loops.